# Report Builder syntax with Firebird ODBC

Tags: sql, syntax, report, firebird

I've been asked to look into creating some reports out of a software that runs with a Firebird database. (I've only ever worked with SQL Server and a bit of Oracle)

I managed to get the ODBC connection set up on my computer, and am working inside of Firebird Maestro for browsing the tables and creating a syntax that runs correctly.

I have some bits that run inside report builder, but when I get into things like INNER JOIN, I'm running into issues.

Here is a bit that works inside Firebird Maestro, but not Report Builder:

```
SELECT Distinct 
    "Personnel"."FirstName",
    "Personnel"."LastName",
    "Transcript"."Score"
FROM 
    "Transcript"
    INNER JOIN "Personnel" 
    ON ("Transcript"."Personnel_ID" = "Personnel"."PersonnelID") 
WHERE
   "Personnel"."FirstName" = 'Aaron'
```

I also have this bit which seems to work in ReportBuilder:

```
SELECT
    "Personnel"."FirstName"
FROM 
    "Personnel"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for syntax?

To reference the error:

[image: Report Builder Error]

Comment: Could you please copy the error as text (on Windows in most popups, you can usually copy the text by using Ctrl+C). The error indicates you have an unexpected '.' (or maybe an apostrophe?) on line 2 column 14. Exactly how did you configure your ODBC datasource? Have you accidentally configured it with dialect 1 (which doesn't supported quoted identifiers, and where double quotes enclose strings) instead of dialect 3 (supports quoted identifiers and strings are enclosed in single quotes)?

Comment: May RepBuilder use SQL Dialect 1 for its connection? Sadly, there seems no SQL request to check the connection dialect, only the database dialect.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing the ODBC settings for the Firebird database, I had to change the dialect to 3, and uncheck quoted identifiers, and all seems to be working in report builder.

Comment: Dialect 3 should be the default anyway, dialect 1 was deprecated back in 2000.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different spellings for the personnel id field in two different tables (with an underscore or without), my guess is that this is a typo, that is causing the error :

```
ON ("Transcript"."Personnel_ID" = "Personnel"."PersonnelID")
```

Comment: Unfortuantely that is how the database table is setup!